# JSON Insert in Mongo

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a JSON Object which I am creating using Gson Library. I want to insert this object in MongoDB using Java Mongo Driver v3.8.1 with UUID as Ids and int64 type for my Integers. However, this seems to be inserting as String and Int32 type respectively.

```
JsonObject folderObject = new JsonObject();
folderObject.addProperty("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
folderObject.addProperty("cid", document.getCid());
```

I am converting this to BSON

```
org.bson.Document doc= org.bson.Document.parse(folderObject .toString());
```

and inserting in MongoDB by using

```
  mongoCollection.insertOne(doc);
```

my document.getCid() is of type Long but is still inserting as int32 and I am unable to pass anything apart from String to the folderObject.

Comment: which mongoDB integration are you using. In mongoose you are able to insert the JSON directly as a new document.

Comment: @SimonThiel I am using Java MongoDriver , mongodb-driver 3.8.1

Comment: Ok, sorry than I can't help you unfortunately

Comment: I highly recommend using [Spring's mongo client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by using Mongo POJO Codec.

```
CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()));

    CodecRegistry codecRegistry =
                fromRegistries(CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(new UuidCodec(UuidRepresentation.STANDARD)),
                        MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),pojoCodecRegistry
                );
```

and then you can choose to start a client with given codec or start a database with the codec registry or the collection with the codec.

Reference - https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/driver/getting-started/quick-start-pojo/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not creat a JsonObject and parse it afterwards:

Can you simply try this:

```
    Document doc = new Document()
            .append("id", UUID.randomUUID())
            .append("cid", document.getCid());
    mongoCollection.insertOne(doc);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Spring for this. The code reads as follows:

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;


public class MyDao {

    private final MongoTemplate template;

    public MyDao(MongoClient client, String db) {
        this.template = new MongoTemplate(client, db);
    }

    public <T extends Serializable> void store(Collection<T> data, String collectionName) {
        template.insert(data, collectionName);
    }


}
```